# Removing comma from between immediate letters or numbers or anything except quotes?

Tags: c#, regex

Is there a way, say a regex even that will remove any commas enclosed in two consecutive quotes and surrounded by letters or numbers?

Not sure what else to do here and this is my last hope before I go looking at CSV Helpers:

I am using Visual Studio SSIS/BI to import text files into a DB. The problem is, SSIS will chock if the file contains data like this:

*"Soccer rocks, yes it does"*

To remedy this, I used a Replace Method which solved the problem temporarily.
I am running this code in Visual Studio BI/SSIS **`Script task`** to process the text file to CSV before sending it to the DB.

```
static void AddComma(string s, TextWriter writer)
{
    foreach (var line in s.Replace(", ", "").Split(new string[] { Environment.NewLine}, StringSplitOptions.None))
    {
        foreach (var t in line)
        {
            writer.Write(t);
        }
        writer.WriteLine();
    }
    writer.Flush();
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    TextReader reader = new StreamReader(@"C:\sample\test.txt");
    string a = reader.ReadToEnd();
    reader.Close();

    FileStream aFile = new FileStream(@"C:\sample\test.csv", FileMode.Create);
    AddComma(a, new StreamWriter(aFile));
    aFile.Close();
}
```

**Note:** I am replacing comma followed by a single space

```
Replace(", ", "");
```

The problem is if the data in the text file looks like this:

*"Soccer rocks,yes it does"*

The Replace method will not catch it, obviously.

Is there a way, say a regex even that will remove any commas enclosed in two consecutive quotes and surrounded by letters or numbers?

So if the data looks like this: "Soccer rocks, yes it does" Or "Soccer rocks 54,23 yes it does" then it will end up like this: "Soccer rocks yes it does"

I am not sure what is possible and simply looking for some kind of solution.

Comment: Use [**`LumenWorks Framework`**](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9258/A-Fast-CSV-Reader) it's a ready to go library that can parse CSV styled data. Your example makes no sense, wouldn't `"Soccer rocks, yes it does"` generate `"Soccer yes it does"` based on the rules you mentioned.

Comment: No, it will simply remove the Comma: "Soccer rocks yes it does" if there is a comma it will be between immediate letters: so Rocks & Yes. I am not implying I know this would work I am just asking what is possible.

Comment: If you remove the comma, you're changing the data sent to you. Maybe the sender doesn't care, maybe the sender does. Reading CSV correctly is a lot more complicated than simply splitting by comma. A Lot of people have had the same need and made libraries to address corner cases you didn't even think about. So why reinvent the wheel?

Comment: There seems to be a long standing [bug in SSIS](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/a1cea026-545d-4548-9358-97a56fca90f2/ssis-bug-when-handling-csv-files-with-commas-embedded-in-quoted-strings) regarding this. In that thread there are some suggested workaround regarding `FlatFileSourceConnection` and `TextQualifier`. That might help you solve your problem *without* altering the data, which I think should be considered only as a last resort.

Comment: I think you should look for a CVS reader, I am sure that there are some free libraries out there to perform the task.

Comment: By the way the LumenWorks Framework does not work. I have posted error on their Blog. Tried Bulk Insert, OpenRowset, nothing works.

Answer (score 1):

did you mean something like [this](http://regexr.com?35ql9)?

if yes, you should use matcher with patern regex `("[\w\s]*),([\w\s]*")`, and get the first and second group then you will get what you need.

if you use c#, that's means you use .net engine regex then you can use infinite repetition lookbehind.

You can try something like this then `s.Replace("(?<="[\w\s]+),(?=[\w\s]+")","-")`, so you can just replace it without needing to get group and match.

Comment: Yes, that may work but on second though maybe I should add a hyphen: Like "Daft Punk well - they rocks!!" Either way, at this point I am just exhausted. :)

Comment: @UnaverageGuy Take a break , this will help

Comment: just replace with $1-$2 then

Comment: @Angga I really don't know much about Regix, except for validation, and I am getting errors about too many s's. Can you explain a bit more?

Comment: `$` is just symbol for group, different language have different symbol for group of regex, what language did you use? [see this link](http://abeytom.blogspot.com/2012/11/java-replace-regex-groups.html) for example.

Comment: I am using C#, anyway, I'll tackle this tomorrow. Thanks you very much.

Comment: i have better solution if you use .NET framework RegEx classes. i edited my answer for that.